# could not complete the operation due to error 8150002e

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, window.open

We are receiving the error message "could not complete the operation due to error 8150002e" when using window.open() from an iframe. The URL we are attempting to open is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGNYL.png)

The code we are using to open the window is:

```js
win = window.open(serviceEndPointsBasicUrl + '/api/SmartVisitReportGenerator/GetSmartVisitOnDemand/' + '?userID=' + self.uUserID() + '&LongDate=' + longDate + '&TimezoneOffset=' + getTimezoneOffset() + '&ContentType=' + self.ChosenContentType() + '&IncludeFoodDiary=' + self.IncludeFoodDiary(), '_blank');
```

Comment: Is this tagged Internet Explorer? What? That still a thing? Also, it seems like there is nothing wrong. We would need to know if all those parts you casually paste together are valid as well, or we can't help you here at all. Have you jusy logged what you pass to `window.open` to see if that URL has a valid structure? No accidental `[Object funtion]` slips etc...

Comment: Yes everything works fine in other browser. But when it comes to Internet explorer and inside the IFrame then we are facing this issue.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but IE isn’t evrn supported by Microsoft anymore. Time to move on or convince your bosses to move on.